# Hibernate ManyToMany Relationship from another Transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a method that creates a `@Transactional` and fetches some entities `A` and creates some entities `B` that have relationship to `A`.

Inside this method, I need to persist an entity `C` that has a `@ManyToMany` relationship to `A`, however this persistence needs to happen no matter what, so in the `save` method of `C's` repository, I add a `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`.

The problem is when I try to persist `C`, the `A's` in the relationship are in another Session.

Is it possible to save `C` and it's `ManyToMany` relationship table without attaching `A` to the session? All the `A's` in the relationship have have been already persisted hence they have ids, and that is all I need to persist in the auxiliary table.